# Update UI from Task Parallel Library issue

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am learning the art of TPL. So I try to update UI in incremental fashion from TPL but I can't get it right. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    int i = 0, flag = 5;
    var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (i < flag)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                this.Text = i.ToString();
                //System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(50000000);
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
            i++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
```

I am trying to update windows title bar UI in incremental fashion. The code runs without exceptions but the UI is not updated until i's value become 5. I want to show it like; 1, then 2 and so on until i is 5.

When I am running my program I noticed that my program hangs until the task is completed or finished.

What am I doing wrong in respect of updating the UI when using tasks?

### another approach 1

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.For(1, 6, i =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(500000000);  do work here   
                BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { this.Text = i.ToString(); });
            });
        });
```

### another approach 2

```
int i = 0, flag = 5;
            var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (i < flag)
                {
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        this.Text = i.ToString();
                    }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
                    i++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.SpinWait(50000000); // do work here   


                }
            }); // <---- Removed arguments (specifically uiScheduler)
```

Comment: What are you asking? What SpinWait does or how to update the UI in a correct fashion using TPL?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for SpinWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx)? Is there anything you don't understand with the docs?

Comment: my code is not update UI i incremental fashion. any idea ?

Comment: I removed the question of SpinWait since it's not really related to you actual question. In short SpinWait "occupies" the CPU, and Thread.Sleep leaves it alone (it sleeps). There's probably a lot of resources to read if you search for "SpinWait vs. Sleep".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're telling the task to use the uiScheduler context when starting the initial task. Remove that and your code should be fine.

```
int i = 0, flag = 5;
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while (i < flag)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            this.Text = i.ToString();
        }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
        i++;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
}); // <---- Removed arguments (specifically uiScheduler)
```

Comment: if i need to initialize a task and run on button click. how can it be possible in dotnet v4.0. can u plzz give me some sample code. thanks

Comment: Just use the code above. Or save the task instead (don't start it) and then run it when the user clicks the button, via a click event. What are you having issues with?